# Temporary table using Transact sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I'm beginner to T-SQL, I have this issue: I'd like to use a **temporary table** without creating it, so I wrote this stored procedure :

```
 create PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_Affaires_By_Client] 
    @clt_nom varchar(255) ,
    @cmd_numero varchar(10),
    @etap_cmd_libelle varchar(50),
    @typ_cmd_libelle varchar(50)
AS 
Begin
    DECLARE @temp_tbl_proc TABLE (cmd_code_pk int NOT NULL,
                                  clt_nom varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                                  cmd_nom varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                  etap_cmd_libelle varchar(50) NULL,
                                  DateAncienTS DateTime NULL,
                                  DateTecentTS DateTime NULL,
                                  TotalHeure numeric(3,2) not null,
                                  TotalHeurePerid numeric(3,2) not null
                                 );


    INSERT INTO @temp_tbl_proc(cmd_code_pk, clt_nom, cmd_numero, cmd_nom, etap_cmd_libelle, typ_cmd_libelle, DateAncienTS, DateTecentTS, TotalHeure, TotalHeurePerid) 
        SELECT        
            ISNULL(cmd_code_pk, 1) AS cmd_code_pk, clt_nom, cmd_numero, 
            cmd_nom, etap_cmd_libelle, typ_cmd_libelle, 
            CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/1900', 103) AS DateAncienTS, 
            CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/1900', 103) AS DateTecentTS, 
            -1.00 AS TotalHeure, -1.00 AS TotalHeurePerid
        FROM    
            OPENQUERY(SAB, 'SELECT c.cmd_code_pk, cl.clt_nom, c.cmd_numero, c.cmd_nom,et.etap_cmd_libelle,ty.typ_cmd_libelle FROM commande c,client cl,etape_commande et, type_commande ty where cl.clt_code_pk=c.cmd_clt_fk and c.cmd_etap_cmd_fk = et.etap_cmd_code_pk and c.cmd_typ_cmd_fk = ty.typ_cmd_code_pk' ) 

    SELECT * 
    FROM @temp_tbl_proc 
    ORDER BY cmd_nom;
END
```

The problems are :

1. the temporary table will be created and added in the database
2. `@@query` and `@query` are not recognized as a valid parameter

So how can I fix these problems?

Comment: First, do not use @@ to reference the @query variable. Use a single @ symbol. Also, what is the error message you're receiving?

Comment: when you write `DECLARE @query varchar;` it is equal `DECLARE @query varchar(1)`  - you have your query length = 1.  And you can delete temporary table after using it `drop table #yourtable`.

Comment: @the.fabricio I used one `@query` but I get this error `Incorrect syntax near ' @query '`

Comment: @xdd please see my edit ==> I get the same result

Comment: I don't see any `#` tables here. And why are you using dynamic sql at all?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I used  `@temp_tbl_proc` as a temporary table

Comment: So you are asking why are you using it? :) why did you decide to introduce this variable into your code? what were your thoughts? you were facing some troubles without it?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I'm using it to avoid passing the parameters of the stored procedure in the query of `OpenQuery` method, I need to temporary store the result of this method then filtring it using the stored procedure's params

Comment: ...but you don't want this table to exist, right?

Comment: `DECLARE @query varchar(255);` - even not better your query length is 278

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes

Comment: I'm afraid Schrödinger's variables not invented yet in sql server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427(v=sql.110).aspx

> OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments.

So you have to craft a dynamic query, or in your cace, just move the query text into the `OPENQUERY`

```
OPENQUERY(SAB, 'Query text comes here')
```

To pass 'parameters', you can follow the instructions described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314520

Essentially you have to craft a dynamic query and execute it as a dynamic query text.

You can use the OPENQUERY() a table in queries:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'QueryText') AS R;
```

Here are some rules to follow:

- Add an alias to each returning columns in the QueryText (SQL Server can't handle anonimous columns),
- Return only the necessary columns (to decrease the network traffic and the load of the remote and local servers)
- You have to add an alias to the OPENQUERY expression in the FROM clause.

So with, a simple example:

```
DECLARE @localCache TABLE (id INT, col1 VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @localCache (id, col1)
SELECT
  id, col1
FROM
  OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, '
    SELECT X.id AS id, Y.col AS col1
    FROM X INNER JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.x_id
  ') src
```

This could be tricky when you have to pass parameters to the remote query, since you have to create a dynamic query. Dynamic queries are executed in a different context, so the original SP's variables are not available.

```
DECLARE @myFilter NVARCHAR(32) = 'foo'

DECLARE @dymanicQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
  INSERT INTO @localCache (id, col1)
    SELECT
      id, col1
    FROM
      OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, ''
        SELECT X.id AS id, Y.col AS col1
        FROM X INNER JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.x_id
        WHERE Y.col2 = ''''' + @myFilter + '''''
      '') src
';

DECLARE @remoteData TABLE (id INT, col1 VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @remoteData (id, col1)
EXEC sp_executesql
  @stmt = @dymanicQuery
```

Please note, that this could be dangerous and in this form it is open for sql injecions.

If you can do it, keep the data in sync in a permanent table (using SSIS for example) and use the synchronised data.

Comment: upvote for the `OpenQuery` issue, but what about the temporary table?

Comment: There is no temp table here (in the question).. You have a table variable which works like a table. It will not create a (visible) physical table in the database. To do so use the `CREATE TABLE` syntax.

Comment: How can I change this to introduce a temporary table? In my case it create a visible physical table when the the stored procedure were called

Comment: well, reading the conv under the question makes me think, that we are facing with an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). So our question is what is your goal? What do you want to achieve (**forget the technical implementation, what is the problem you want to solve**)

Comment: ok I explain , I have a Sql server database with a linked server to a Mysql database, I need to create a stored procedure with params which uses datas from the linked database, because the `OpenQuery` method is limited So I think to get the whole remote  view or table and store it temporary in a table then filtring the result (content of the table) and return it.

Comment: Do you get any kind of errors using your edited query in the question?

Comment: When I call the stored procedure for the first time the table is created then in the second time an error appears indicates that the table exists !!

Comment: Which table? the variable? another table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118434/discussion-between-lamloumi-afif-and-pred).

Comment: @LamloumiAfif `that the table exists` add full error message to your question post.